Diffrence between these 2 lenses
I have a DX AF-P NIKKOR 70-300mm 1:4.5-5.63G ED LENS. is it worth getting a Nikon 70-300mm f4.5-5.6AF-P ED VR LENS. Is there a benefit?

Do you have other lenses? What benefit are you expecting? What do you use them for?

What problem are you having with the lens you have now that you think the other lens can solve? What pictures do you want to take that your current lens can't?

Different lenses but the same issue of marginal differences between one you have and one you don't have: What are the differences between these lenses... and Beginner kit improvement advice - which lens should I consider? and What improvements I could expect upgrading from Canon EF 55-250mm IS to a Canon 70 - 300mm?

If the first one is actually a Nikon AF-P DX NIKKOR 70-300mm f/4.5-6.3G ED, the second one is a bit more open at the long end (f/5.6 instead of f/6.3) and has an optical shake reduction ("VR").
Independently of possible better optical quality (you can google tests...) the increased aperture will help your camera focus more accurately (or focus better in poor light), and the VR system, by stabilizing the image in the viewfinder (and on the focus sensor), will help you focus on specific parts of the image (for instance a bird among the branches), and let the camera focus on a still subject.

But if it is not really sharper (after watching some tests) I doubt the change is worth it.

If it is about as sharp you will probably still get better focused pictures. On a tele lens, accurate focusing is important and camera shake impairs it. You don't care about sharpness if you have blurry pictures.

@xenoid On the pother hand, if it is mounted on a solid platform such as a good tripod, then adding VR is purely superfluous.

@MichaelC yes, but there are plenty of places where us amateurs can't use a tripod (or even a monopod). Not saying that VR/IS is the panacea, but on these lenses it makes quite a difference in ease of use.

Does the fact that one's DX and the other's full frame matter? I'm surprised no one has pointed that out...

The FF lens can be a bit heavier. But the OP is asking about the benefits :-)

@xenoid And we have absolutely no idea if the OP has the ability to use a tripod/monopod/fixed mount or not, do we? Thus the answer would be better served to make allowances for either possibility, not just one of them.
